# Многомерный динамический массив

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите, как создать многомерный динамический массив.
Пример:
было
`int a[4][4][4]`
теперь хочу как-то так
`int b;`
`cin >> b;`
`int * a = new int[b][b][b] //так не работает`
по аналогии с
`int * a = new int[]`
Необходимо что-то подобное, чтобы сильно не переписывать готовый код.

Comment: Можно, конечно, вкладывать указатели в указатели, но это скорее ради практики с указателями. Потому что по соображениям производительности (времени, памяти, а также фрагментации последней) лучше так не делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы было проще переписывать, используйте классы.

```
// g++-9 -Wall -std=c++98 -Wextra -Wpedantic cube.cpp -o cube
class cube  {
public :
  cube(int dim);
  ~cube();
  int & elt(int i,int j,int k);
private :
  int d ;
  int * ap ;
} ;

# include <iostream>
using std :: cin ;

int main(){
  int b ;
  cin >> b ;
  cube  cub(b);
  cub.elt(1,1,1) = 7;
}

cube::cube(int dim):d(dim),ap() {
  ap = new int [ d * d * d ] ; }

cube :: ~ cube () {
  delete [] ap ; }

int & cube :: elt (int i,int j,int k) {
  return ap [ k + ( j  + i * d ) * d ] ; }
```

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста эту строчку

cube::cube(int dim):d(dim),ap() {

Вы тут определяете конструктор класса, верно...
не понимаю, что происходить после cube::cube(int dim).

Comment: Обязательно нужно вызывать конструкторы всех внутренних переменных класса. `d(dim)` это просто присваивание, а `ap()` - обнуление.

Comment: точно, было дело, понял

Comment: `-std=c++98`!? *тут должна быть дежурная шутка про потёкшую криокамеру, но её тогда, наверно, ещё не придумали* =)... и, кстати, если быть более педантичным, чем `gcc`, то инициализация в конструкторе пустым инициализатором вида `ap()` в этот стандарте ещё нет.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так

```
// создание
int h, w, d; cin >> h >> w >> d;

int*** data = new int**[h];

for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
    data[i] = new int* [w];
    for (int y = 0; y < w; ++y) {
        data[i][y] = new int[d];
    }
}

// удаление
for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
    for (int y = 0; y < w; ++y) {
        delete[]  data[i][y];
    }
    delete[] data[i];
}
delete[] data;
```

---

А теперь по подробнее.

`int h, w, d; cin >> h >> w >> d;` - как обычно, переменные высота, ширина, глубина массива.

`int*** data = new int**[h];` - создаём указатель на будущий массив двумерных массивов (он же трёхмерных массив).

Далее выделяем память под каждый двумерных массив (`data[i] = new int* [w];`), и для каждого двумерного массива выделяем память для его одномерных массивов (`data[i][y] = new int[d];`).

Ну и удаление - те же действия, только наоборот.

---

Пример использования (заполнение массива)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int h, w, d; std::cin >> h >> w >> d;

    int*** data = new int**[h];

    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        data[i] = new int* [w];
        for (int y = 0; y < w; ++y) {
            data[i][y] = new int[d];
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0, c = 0; k < h; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
            for (int y = 0; y < d; ++y, ++c) {
                data[k][i][y] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < h; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
            for (int y = 0; y < d; ++y) {
                std::cout << data[k][i][y] << " ";
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (int y = 0; y < w; ++y) {
            delete[]  data[i][y];
        }
        delete[] data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

> 10 5 3

Output:

> 0 1 2 3 ... 149

Comment: C++ я только учу, поправьте если что не так `:)`

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!)
Завтра попробую и отпишу.

Comment: Стоит оговориться, что хотя это и обычная практика среди неофитов, и внешне очень похоже на работу с массивом на стеке, но структурно это совсем другое представление данных и это связано с определёнными издержками в производительности.